# Debugging C++ shared library from a C# app run in a linux docker container

Tags: c#, linux, docker, debugging, shared-libraries

My .NET C# project calls C++ shared library code via p/invoke (dllimport). It is also run in alpine linux container.
I've set up a docker compose project in Visual Studio, checked the "allow debugging native code" option in the C# project, compiled .so with the debug symbols and copied it to /usr/lib.
The docker compose project runs well in Visual Studio - loading the DLL, triggering the debugger and stopping at a specific C# breakpoint. But it won't step into C++ DLL code. Is that even possible to do?